# how to retrieve data on compare time in php

Tags: php, json, time

My code:

```
$query =    "INSERT IGNORE INTO `user_app` (app_id,imei, package_name, sdk_name, sdk_version, app_version)
                VALUES 
                ('".$appid."','".$imei."', '".$pkg."', '".$sdkn."', '".$sdkv."', '".$appv."')"; 

    $mysqli -> query($query);

    $id = $mysqli -> insert_id ; //get last user insert id

    $idt = date('G:i:s', time());

    $new = strtotime($idt);

    include('requestad.php');
```

When a new user registered, he'll get an ad from requestad.php in json format. Insert id is save in a separate variable named $id, if a user again hit via application (as application invoke after every 30min ) then he'll get again json ad. I am trying to do some stuff like user get ad only once in whole 24hours, this is possible with insert id and insert time stamp. I am doing something like that:

```
if ( $new == time() ) {

        include('requestad.php');

    } elseif ( $new < time() ) {

            echo 'nothing';

    }
```

But problem is i didn't save exact execution time in variable and save time is necessary for comparison. Also, i have to send some blank to user if he again request for resource. Pl have a look on this and help me to produce optimal solution.
Still i didn't apply any logic yet. I can achieve this through store time which is static and compare it to time() which shows real time. Still i am looking this one

Comment: I didn't understand what you were trying to do but using `==` in the `if ($new=time())` is probably what you ment there

Comment: what issue? are you not able to compare the current hit time to first hit time?

Comment: @HarshalMahajan :yeah, i ain't able to compare time exactly.

Comment: @YaronUliel: When a new user registered, i'll save insert id and time to track user. If user again request for ad then he didn't get any ad in whole day!

Comment: you are comparing the  $new = strtotime($idt);to time(),but you have to compare by converting both the time in strtotime.you didnt convert time(); to strtotime.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan: but time() already prints Unix timestamp, and strtotime convert given time string to unix timestamp!

Comment: than you have to make some change in your logic,see pick up the current time,than pick the first time of user,less the -24 hours from current time and than compare the store time to current time.make condition if current tiem is == or greater than current time than call the storead.php.hope this works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16087/discussion-between-shihon-and-harshal-mahajan)

Answer (score 0):

```
$store_time=$row['time'];//pick up the store time of user 

$store_time=strtotime($row['time']);//and convert it in strtotime.if alredy did no need to do this.

$new=strtotime("-24 hours",strtotime(time()));//substract the time to -24 hours.

if($new==$store_time)
{
//your code
}
else
{
//your code
}
```